# C# Wrapper for C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm working on an app that I would really like to write in C#, but I need to use a library that is in C++. The vendor supplements their DLL with some C++ code to make the API more convenient, which it does, but it's still C++. I'd like to incorporate this extra C++ code into my app. It seems reasonable to create a DLL to wrap the vendor-supplied C++ code and the other calls into a module that I can use in C#.

My question is, does it make sense to wrap a DLL in another DLL? Are the potential problems I should watch out for?

Best,
John

Comment: I suggest taking the part provided by source, and turning that into C++/CLI.  C++/CLI code can use C++ libraries directly, whether via static linking or as a DLL.  And in turn C++/CLI code compiles to a .NET assembly, and can contain .NET types that are directly usable from C#.  The catch is that since .NET types are moved around by the garbage collector, you can't put those and C++ native types in the same memory block.  But they can have pointers to each other just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a wrapper for the sake of creating a better API (or, in your case, a .NET API) is OK. You might face some interop problems, as they can always pop up when moving from managed to unmanaged code.